# Adding redux dispatch method to connected component props in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

This might be more of a design question than anything, but I'm trying to develop a connected component in typescript and it needs the dispatch method because modals are a bit of a special snowflake in that they're sort of in the DOM and just shown and hidden.  This creates a unique problem in that `mapDispatchToProps` is only called once when model is first used in the DOM (expected behavior).  Subsequent calls will correctly invoke the `componentWillReceiveProps` method but the `dispatch` method is not available as a method parameter.  Thus, the first time executed, the `ownProps` value in `mapDispatchToProps` won't contain the "right" properties.

Given the code below, the `connect` method will place the `dispatch` method on the component's props.  This is why the method can be pulled from the deconstructed props in the `render` method.  But putting the dispatch code in the `render()` method here feels wrong and I don't have a good alternative.  Thoughts?

**NB**: Please focus on the question rather than critiquing syntax, content, etc...unless materially related.  Thanks.

```
export interface IModalContainerProps {
  isOpen: boolean
  modalType?: ConfirmationModalType
  cancelAction?: string
  successAction?: string
  dispatch?: (action: Action) => void
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state: any): any => {
  return {
    isOpen: isModalOpen(state),
    modalType: getModalType(state),
    successAction: getSuccessAction(state),
    cancelAction: getCancelAction(state)
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps: any) => {
  return {
    dispatch
  }
}

class MC extends React.Component<IModalContainerProps> {

  public static defaultProps: Partial<IModalContainerProps> = {
    isOpen: false,
    modalType: null
  }

  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IModalContainerProps): void {
    console.log('updated props', nextProps)
  }

  @Bind()
  public render(): React.ReactElement<MC> {
    console.log('rendering modal')
    const { isOpen, modalType, cancelAction, successAction, dispatch } = this.props

    const handleCancel = () => {
      dispatch({ type: cancelAction })
    }
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      dispatch({ type: successAction })
    }

    return (
      <BaseModal automationTag={'hello'} containerClass={'goodbye'} isOpen={isOpen}>
        <!-- TODO: make generic -->
        <ConfirmationModal type={modalType} handleCancel={handleCancel} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
      </BaseModal>
    )
  }
}
export const ModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely get what it is you're trying to do, but since nobody has answered you here's a potential solution.

I wouldn't pass `dispatch()` to your component. You can define your `handleCancel()` and `handleSubmit()` in `mapDispatchToProps()` and pass them whatever you want. Something like this:

```
interface IIModalContainerDispatchProps {
    handleCancel: (type: string) => void;
    handleSubmit: (type: string) => void;
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>): IIModalContainerDispatchProps => {
    return {
        handleCancel: function (cancelAction: string): void {
            dispatch({ type: cancelAction });
        },
        handleSubmit: function (successAction: string): void {
            dispatch({ type: successAction });
        }
    };
}
```

And then you can call `this.props.handleCancel(cancelAction)` and `this.props.handleSubmit(submitAction)` within your component. Unless I've completely misunderstood what you're trying to do.

To get the types working properly you need to combine your dispatch and state props.

```
export interface IModalContainerStateProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    modalType?: ConfirmationModalType;
    cancelAction?: string;
    successAction?: string;
}

type IModalContainerProps = IIModalContainerDispatchProps & IModalContainerStateProps;
```

Comment: I've seen examples where `dispatch` is used as in my code - it just feels wrong to reference it in the render method as we're actually wiring in the handlers at that point.  It seems like it should be done ahead of time.  That said, again, modals are special snowflakes in that they have to be in the DOM at some point and just shown/hidden which maybe just necessitates that the event handlers are dynamic.  Even react-modal's examples place the modal in the DOM and just show/hide it via state.